# How to Properly load ENC charts on QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, chart, s-57

[image]I am trying to load ENC charts on QGIS but they are very odd when loaded. I read that one has to use ogr2ogr that converts these to shapefiles but that didn't work for me too. It shows up totally different. Can anyone guide. I downloaded sample charts from [NOAA](https://www.charts.noaa.gov/ENCs/ENCs.shtml) website.

I expect it to load it like this.This is opened on openCPN:
[image]

Comment: can you add a screen shot to show us what "very odd" means

Comment: ...and please cite the NOAA website URL.

Comment: Edited the Post. Sorry for incomplete information

Comment: What are you expecting to see? That looks about right to me.

Comment: @DaveC I edited the post for you to see what I'm expecting. I'd really appreciate any hints.

Comment: as @J.R has mentioned in his answer I think you just need to style it. The files themselves don't usually hold styling unless you use specific types.

Answer (score 1):

It seem that QGIS import the data correctly, if it look different it's because it's not symbolized (QGIS use random color on default symbology without any label) , you will need to do it manually or to find some pre-made QGIS style file to achieve the look you're after.

If you happens to read and understand french (or are not put off by automated translation) this blog post : ["Affichage des cartes marines S57 dans QGis"](https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/affichage-des-cartes-marines-s57-dans-qgis/) will guide you to the whole import process including downloading and using symbology[(download link)](http://www.nasca.ovh/downloads/qgis_nautical.zip).

This blog post also state that the relevant symbology is also accessible by using the "Resource Sharing" plugin  and looking for the "Nautical symbols for marine charts" collection

EDIT : these link are quite old but still work (september 2016) and refer to old QGIS version (2.6 or 2.8)  I haven't test it so I can't say if everything will just work or if you will need to adapt a bit...